# Scrape only large(HD) images from google using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

Here I am using this code to take screenshot of images from google and save it in a directory.
But it takes small images as well, so how shall I keep a condition such that it **scrapes** only large (HD) images.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Path_to_driver/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/')

box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
box.send_keys('mobile phone camera')
box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hdtb-msb"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a').click()


#Will keep scrolling down the webpage until it cannot scroll no more
last_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
while True:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
    time.sleep(2)
    new_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    print(new_height)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="islmp"]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/input').click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
a = 1500

for i in range(1,50):
    a +=1
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div['+str(i)+']/a[1]/div[1]/img').screenshot('./images/ ('+str(a)+').png')
    except:
        pass
```

Any suggestion would be great as I am new to selenium.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a Tools option in google images, where you can select only search results with large images, and also instead of taking screenshot, I'd suggest you to fetch all the image source and then download the images individually, which is better than taking screenshots of the images in my opinion.

You can even take it further by clicking on each image in the search results and grab the image source links from there, which would give you the original quality images.

I'm attaching some images for your reference.

1- Google image tools option

[image: google images tools option]

2- Thumbnail image source link

[image: image source link]

3- Original image source link (Need to click on the image for this)

[image: original image source link]